# Make background fill all white space CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a background image which works fine for the most part, however after changing the view to an iPhone 11 for example in Dev Tools, I noticed that the background stops after a certain point. I have included the CSS where the image is held below, can I add anything to fill the gap? [image]

```
.app::before {
 content: '';
 background: url('./assets/backgroundImg.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `overflow: hidden` to my styling for all

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
```